# Intel igpu drivers in ubuntu 22.04 (i5 12600k, uhd 770)

Tags: intel, gpu-driver, davinci-resolve

I've a i5 12600k (uhd 770) with 8gb ram and no gpu. But, i can't find any source or tutorial on how to install drivers for this igpu. And without the drivers, I'm unable to run "Davinci Resolve" and games lag a lot.

Hope you guys will help me. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to install additional drivers for the integrated UHD graphics to work. They're built in. Davinci Resolve is unlikely to work well on that integrated graphics chip.